# flask-wtform placeholder behavior

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Form:

```
class SignUpForm(Form):
    username = TextField("Username: ",validators=[Required(),Length(3,24)])
```

why does this work?

```
form = SignUpForm()
form.username(placeholder="username")
```

but not when you directly use placeholder as an  argument for the `SignUpForm`?

```
class SignUpForm(Form):
        username = TextField("Username: ",placeholder="username",validators=[Required(),Length(3,24)])
```

it gives out this error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'placeholder'`

Im a bit puzzled by this because defining it directly on the class should just be the same as
doing `form.username(placeholder="username")`  but why does it give out an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Calling a field to render it accepts arbitrary keyword args to add attributes to the input.](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__) If you want a shortcut to render a field with the label as the placeholder, you can write a Jinja macro.

```
{% macro form_field(field) %}
{{ field(placeholder=field.label.text) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

You can also provide args to pass to each render call when defining the field by setting the `render_kw` argument.

```py
username = TextField(render_kw={"placeholder": "username"})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'render_kw' in order to use placeholder in your form class.

```
class SignUpForm(Form):
        username = TextField("Username: ", render_kw={"placeholder": "username"}, validators=[Required(),Length(3,24)])
```